# UPDATE OR INSERT TABLE ON DUPLICATED KEY

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I want to make the add values every 10 min.

can you help me what is wrong on this sql?

I want to make COUNTS = T1.COUNTS + T2.COUNTS

Code is below.

```
 INSERT INTO IMC_WDS_ROW_PROCESS_HOUR_TABLE_copy T1  
 (AP_ADDR,YM,YMD,YMDH,`YEAR`,`MONTH`,`DAY`,`HOUR`,`WEEK`,`WEEKEND`,`WEEKOFYEAR`,`COUNTS`,`DUR_SUM`,      `DUR_MAX`,`DUR_MIN`)
 SELECT  AP_ADDR,YM,YMD,YMDH,`YEAR`,`MONTH`,`DAY`,`HOUR`,`WEEK`,`WEEKEND`,`WEEKOFYEAR`,`COUNTS`,`DUR_SUM`,       `DUR_MAX`,`DUR_MIN`
 FROM IMC_UPDATE_TABLE T2
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 

 `COUNTS`= VALUES(T1.COUNTS)+VALUES(T2.COUNTS)
```

thaks.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 YM=YM+T2.YM ...` surely?